# Flask token based password recovery / resetting How to?

Tags: flask, token, recovery

I need to enable reset/recovery passwords on site
On flask I want to realize method to generate token if user reset pwd.
Then sending url to user email (example http://example.com/?token=huih23ui4h235h324h5oi)
to confirm reset pwd.
After user confirm reset pwd on this url, I generate new pwd, update DB and send this pwd to user.

How can I do this? May be exist some modules or libs?

Comment: Probably Flask Security (it has a lot of features, so maybe more than you need since you'd have to replace your current login system)? https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/

Comment: hi! NO its not a variant to replace login system. I need only realize token reset

Comment: Can't you generate a hash with a python's [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html), save it on your database and then confirm the hash is correct to allow the password change?

Comment: Thanks! I am already do this. Create new table with user id,confirm_status and expires. Then wrote router and method for cheking valid hash if ok send new password to user email

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ItsDangerous](http://packages.python.org/itsdangerous/) library.

```
user_id = 1
password = 'shh!'

from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer
s = URLSafeSerializer('super-secret-key')
print s.dumps([user_id, password])
## WzEsInNoaCEiXQ.kt-4CV03gNXcN86xuRIgunbW0Sw
```

So you'd send them the link with that token.  Then when they click it, you decode it:

```
print s.loads('WzEsInNoaCEiXQ.kt-4CV03gNXcN86xuRIgunbW0Sw')
## [1, u'shh!']
```

And compare it with the database to see if they have already changed the password, if not-- let them change it.  You can also add in a timestamp to allow you to set time restrictions on password changing.

Comment: Very thank you!!! It's easier than my method.
May be in future i will use itsdangerous

Answer (score 2):

Heyo!

@doobeh is right -- itsdangerous is the best library out there for handling this stuff directly.

If you're looking for a 'simpler solution', however, you might want to check out [flask-stormpath](http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It handles that token generation stuff for you, as well as a lot of other stuff around it (expiring tokens, etc.).

For password reset here's what it would look like:

1. User initiates password reset on a web page.
2. Stormpath sends out reset email to user (your "from" address, custom HTML, etc) with a link + token.  The reset token that is unique, one-time use, and expires if not used within 24 hours
3. User clicks on the link and lands on the reset page
4. You pull the token from the URL and check Stormpath for token verification
5. User submits new password
6. Stormpath sends out reset success message (your "from" address, custom HTML, etc)

I'm the author of flask-stormpath and work at stomrpath, so I'm a bit biased, but it is quite nice for this use case.

Comment: The Stormpath API shut down on August 17, 2017. - https://stormpath.com/